# Truncation Error when I try to create a Array of values

Tags: java

I want a create a array of values with a interval of 0.2
I used the code :

```
public class TrialCode {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    float a = -1.0f, b = 0.2f;

    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        a = a + b;
        System.out.println(a);

    }

}

}
```

Now the output that i am getting is :

```
-0.8
-0.6
-0.40000004
-0.20000003
-2.9802322E-8
0.19999997
0.39999998
0.59999996
0.79999995
0.99999994
```

whereas the output I want is

```
-0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want floating-point arithmetic, then don't use floating-point types. `Float` and `Double` aren't the only non-integral `Number`s in the Java core library. What you're doing calls for `BigDecimal`.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TrialCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("-1.0");
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.2");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            a = a.add(b);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Floating point numbers only work up to a certain precision. For `float` it is 6-7 significant digits, for `double` it is 15-16 significant digits. And due to the binary representation simple decimal fractions like 0.1 cannot be represented exactly.

You can round the output to get the results you want:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f", a);
```

Comment: I was about to answer this.

Comment: does java has printf or it might be println ?

Comment: @ItayB yes to [use format string you need to use printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: @ItayB printf is available since Java 1.5

Comment: @ItayB Note in print **f** ,  `f` stands for 'format' (but not for file)

Comment: Yes, but this approach will eventually fail, if you add 0.2 enough times.  You're only hiding the effect, not removing it.  A better solution would be to use a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @DavidWallace That really depends on the application. `BigDecimal` will show the same problems for other simple increments like one third. Moreover it is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(0.19999997); //"0.2"
```